# Using multiple navigators in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator

It seems as though whenever you need to use multiple navigators within a RN app, you get an invariant error. Specifically, my problem is referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417144/create-a-side-menu-home-page-with-react-native-navbar-react-native-router-flux), where I attempt to create an application with a login screen that leads to a side menu navigation page (the home feed screen).

Is there any way to implement this?

Currently, I have the repo here: https://github.com/robtg4/template

and I am getting this error:

[image]

Running this in my packager:

```
{
  "name": "blackness",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-navbar": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.17.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post an RNPlay with the isolated issue, and the React Native version you are using. I am using multiple Navigators with no issue.

Comment: @JohnShammas here is the repo https://github.com/robtg4/template